# Program to find if a number is perfect

Tags: c

I'm having trouble trying to run this program that I made to find if a number if perfect. It gives me a segmentation error. What does that mean? Can you help me to understand what I did wrong? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void perfect(int number);

int main() {
    int n;

    printf("Insert a number greater than 0: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    perfect(n);

    return 0;
}

void perfect(int number) {
    int i, j, array[100], k = 0, tmp = 0, tmp2 = number;

    for (i = 2; i <= 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j <= 1000; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                array[k] = i;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    k = 0;

    while (tmp2 != 1) {
        if (tmp2 % array[k] == 0) {
            tmp += array[k];
            tmp2 /= array[k];
        }
        k++;
    }

    tmp++;
    if (tmp == tmp2) {
        printf("It's a perfect number\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess buffer overflow on `array`. You're only declaring room for 100, then looping over 1000. Maybe the math works out and you're fine, I don't know. Put a conditional breakpoint at the `array[k]=i;` line for when `k` > 99 and see if it gets hit.

Comment: @yano What's a conditional breakpoint?

Comment: It's a breakpoint that breaks only when a condition is met. It's helpful in a case like this when the problem might occur only after several iterations through a loop. If `k` ever becomes > 99 in that double `for` loop, then you'll access `array` out of bounds, invoking undefined behavior. If you simply put a breakpoint at `array[k] = i;`, you'll have a lottttt of stepping through to do before the part that could be causing the problem (`k` > 99). If you've never used a debugger before, now is an excellent time to learn.

Comment: @yano I've set the array as array[10000] and it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the conditional breakpoint never gets hit, then you can eliminate that double `for` loop as the problem and move on to the `while` loop. If you really don't want to mess with a debugger, `printf` the value of `k` right before `array[k] = i;`. If `k` is ever > 99,, there's your undefined behavior which in your case is manifesting itself as a seg fault. A debugger will also tell you which line it's crashing on.

Comment: well, you are looping ~one million times, 1000 over 1000. Potentially that could make `k` ~1000000. (It won't because of the condition, but it might get bigger than 9999). One way or another you need to figure out what `k` is before you write or read from `array[k]`. Any access beyond its bounds, even by 1, invokes undefined behavior, and your program could do anything after that.

Comment: A segmentation fault ordinarily arises from an out-of-bounds array access or from dereferencing a null or wild pointer.  That might be an issue for you even with `array` dimensioned at 10000.  But more importantly, your approach to the problem is at best extremely obtuse.  You do not need `array` at all, or anything like it, to solve this problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What I was trying to do is find prime numbers between 1 and 1000 and then find if a number inserted by the user between 1 and 1000 is prime.

Comment: @user10198594, testing whether a number is perfect does not require identifying primes, which is good because your code does not appear to successfully discover primes anyway.  You just need to find the proper divisors of the input number -- all of them, not just the prime ones -- and add them up.

Comment: FWIW, in my tests, your `while` loop fails to terminate for at least some inputs before it runs off the end of the populated part of `array`.

Comment: @user10198594 You need to rethink the design of your program. A [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a number that is equal to the sum of its proper divisors. For example, 28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14. Notice that it's **not** the sum of the prime divisors, which would be 2 + 2 + 7.

Comment: There is a simpler solution: `if (n==6 || n==28 || n==496 || n==8128 || n==33550336) puts("It's a perfect number");` (Although you'll have to add another 3 numbers to the list if your `int` size is 64 bits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the loop index maximum value `1000`, the array `array` should be defined with a size of at least `1001`.  With a size of `100`, you likely have a buffer overflow causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault tells you that you are trying to access memory outside the bounds of what you are allowed. Your array is nowhere near big enough for what your program does.

You need to reconsider what you are storing in array. All numbers up to a thousand that are divisible by other numbers, right? But actually it's going to be

- all of them **and**
- all the even ones **and**
- all of them that are divisible by 3 **and**
- all of them that are divisible by 4 etc.

That sounds like a lot more than 100 doesn't it? There will also be many, many repeats which I doubt you intend. For example, you will store 6 three times as it is divisible by 2, 3 and itself. (So, by the way, you should stop looking once j is greater than i.)

Your while loop is also peculiar. It terminates when tmp2 is 1. How is tmp ever going to be equal to 1?

Back to the drawing board, I'm afraid!